# Calculating future states

Tags: java, matlab, probability, prediction, hidden-markov-models

I am working with HMM to predict the future states of a sequence. Using forward algorithm I can calculate following probability.

[image]

And I need a way to calculate the prediction probability;

[image]

for an example when h=2, it is ; [image]

Is there any library or code in java (or matlab) which provides calculation algorithm for prediction probability :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling this? Also, this looks like it comes under the category of questions known as "requesting a resource". This isn't a type of question well suited for SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Yes.Thanks for comment